# How to get data from a private API and add it to wordpress pages

Tags: plugins, rest-api, api

I got a private API ([Cliniko](https://github.com/redguava/cliniko-api)) I want for example the full list of clients to be listed where I want on a page.
I know how APIs work, what I don't know is how to implement them in Wordpress.

Is there a plugin that can help me do it? Or, what's the better way to do it?

And yes I have searched google up to page 10(and clicked almost every single link) I have seen lots of guides or maybe things that can work but nothing consistent, and almost everything that could be good is at least 3 years old, that's why I'm asking here, so please don't be *****.
Thank you very much for any help, that's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data using `wp_remote_get()`.

```
//API URL
$url = 'your api url';

// API RESPONSE
$response = wp_remote_get($url, "your headers goes here / use array to set multiple headers.");
```

you can then access content from `$response`.

```
$response['body']; // will give you content.
```

wrap it with your own function name and add this code in your `functions.php` file. Call the function from your `custom page template file`.

Comment: That looks like a good idea, I'll try that as soon as I get home!

Comment: Sure, let us know if it works for you.